# Program for capturing audio as an audio file

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

I am interesting in generating an audio file (mp3, wma...) instead of having the sound coming out of the speaker.

For example, I press record, play one or multiple sound on my computer (movie, website, windows sound...) and after a while I press stop and it gives me an audio file of everything that went trough the speakers during that period.

I don't want something that record the sound that is played, but rather capture it before it is outputed. So if I play back the generated file, I have the exact same quality as when I recorded it.

Does such a program exists?

Comment: Note that mp3 is a lossy format, so if you create mp3s, you do not have "the exact same quality as when [you] recorded[...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you don't even need a program to do this. Here's how to do it with windows 7:

- Right click on the sound icon, and then click `recording devices`.
  [image: sound icon]
- right click on the default microphone, and click `disable`
  [image: disable default microphone]
- Right click on line, and click `enable`.
  [image: enable line]
- Then you have to record. Type "record" in the windows search, and click `sound recorder`
  [image: sound recorder]
- Now you can play your music, video or sounds, press the record button, wait for it to finish and press `Stop recording`. Windows will prompt you to save it as a WMA file.

Edit: In order to have `line` available in the recording list, you have to install virtual audio cable, or streaming audio recorder.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Choose or install an audio recording program such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) which can record audio as MP3

**Step 2**: Make it possible for that program to record your audio-out channel. Choose **one** of

- Select "Wave-out mix" or "Stereo mix" if your soundcard drivers support this (some do, some don't. *Thanks to [Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) for reminding us of this*). *Or*
- Connect a real audio cable between line-out and line-in on your sound card. Select line-in and turn off recording-monitoring. *Or*
- Install [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) and read it's documentation carefully.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to record audio played on the computer with audacity. I am interested to record the "internal sound", before it comes out of the speakers for a better quality.

Comment: @pinouchon: Something like 1. connect a cable between line-out and line-in. 2. start Audacity. 3. choose "record". I'm not at my audio-recording PC right now. Details later maybe.

Comment: There's also the built in "stereo mix" in many audio chipsets...

Comment: @Bob: Good point. I'll reorganise my answer for clarity and include that.